# How do I pass multiple options to an NLTagger enumeration process?

Tags: objective-c, nlp

Here's the code:

```
#import <NaturalLanguage/NaturalLanguage.h>

...

NSString *taggerString = @"I was outside alone.";

NLTagger *tagger = [[NLTagger alloc] initWithTagSchemes:@[NLTagSchemeLemma]];

tagger.string = taggerString;

[tagger enumerateTagsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, taggerString.length)
                        unit:NLTokenUnitWord
                      scheme:NLTagSchemeLemma
                     options:NLTaggerOmitWhitespace
                  usingBlock:^(NLTag _Nullable tag,
                               NSRange tokenRange,
                               BOOL * _Nonnull stop){
    
    NSString *word = [taggerString substringWithRange:tokenRange];
    
    NSLog(@"Word: %@ Tag: %@", word, tag);
}];
```

In the options parameter I'd like to pass both **NLTaggerOmitWhitespace** and **NLTaggerOmitPunctuation** so it removes the "." in the end.

How do I pass multiple options?

Answer (score 1):

Using the syntax:

```
options:(Option 1 | Option 2 | ...)
```

For the use case above:

```
[tagger enumerateTagsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, taggerString.length)
                        unit:NLTokenUnitWord
                      scheme:NLTagSchemeLemma
                     options:(NLTaggerOmitWhitespace | NLTaggerOmitPanctuation)
                  usingBlock:^(NLTag _Nullable tag,
                               NSRange tokenRange,
                               BOOL * _Nonnull stop){
    
    NSString *word = [taggerString substringWithRange:tokenRange];
    
    NSLog(@"Word: %@ Tag: %@", word, tag);
}];
```